# Does this sentence below mean what I try to say?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does 'an adult was a baby' mean 'an adult is a person who was a baby'? For example, 'a red apple was green' may make sense according to ['Good Girl Gone Bad,' isn't it paradox?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270301/good-girl-gone-bad-isnt-it-paradox).

Comment: I don't seem to get what you're trying to say…

Comment: Do you mean 'every adult was once a baby'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"An adult was a baby"  is a complete sentence.  It is a true sentence.  It describes one true fact about all adults.

Normally you would write using the plural

> All adults were babies.

"An adult is a person who was a baby" is a definition of "Adult". It is not a correct definition, since a 10-year-old child is also a "person who was a baby" but a  10-year-old child is not an adult.

"A red apple was green" is a statement that may be true or not. Usually it is not true. Most apples don't change colour.  It is not a paradox.

"a small big dot" is an *oxymoron*, not a paradox.  It states that something has two properties that are contradictory.

You should look up the words "paradox", "contradiction" and "oxymoron" in your bilingual dictionary (and perhaps also check the meaning in your native language because these are difficult words in any language)

"This sentence is false" is a paradox.  It is a statement that if it is true, then asserts its own falsehood. This is a logical paradox. Here is another one:

> "Yields a false statement when preceded by its quotation" yields a false statement when preceded by its quotation.

The word "paradox" is also used for statements that appear to be false but are actually true, or statements that appear to be true, but are actually false: "If women are stronger than men in science, and women are stronger than men in Arts.  Then women are stronger than men when you combine science and art".  This is Simpson's paradox. It seems to be true. It is actually false.

As you see there is a difference between a "paradox", an "oxymoron" and a "false statement". Most false statements are not paradoxes.

Comment: Thank you, but aside from this question, is 'there's a small big dot' also not a paradox?

Comment: because some people say the dot is big but some people say the dot is small so I think the dot can be both big and small.

Comment: It is still an oxymoron.  Did you look up those words?

Comment: I got itttttt XD thanks

Answer (score 0):

I consider the statement to be true. Every adult must have been, at some point, a baby. However, I think it's more concerned with how that adult has *acted*. They will have done ssomething childish, thus being described as a baby.

'He took the news badly, and stamped around for ages. He was a baby.' Taking your sentence literally.